# Is it safe to use ASP server side includes in the head section?

Tags: asp-classic, server-side-includes

I would like to have a common head section (for `meta` tags etc) across all pages. Can I use something like:

```
<head>
<!--#include file="head.asp"--> 
</head>
```

to do this? Also, must ASP server side includes contain matching tags, or can I open a tag in one `include` and close it in another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this. You can put an include file anywhere you want as long as it does not contain something that needs to be at a specific location. E.g. an include file containing `<%@ language="vbscript" %>` must be included at the very beginning of your script.

Secondly it is OK to open a tag in one file and close it in another but normally is poor practice and you have to be careful.

In case you want to check the order of HTML + raw ASP code you can rename the external file from `.asp` to `.shtml`. When a shtml file is viewed over IIS, it will process all #include statements but it will not execute the ASP code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. It's safe.

> Also, must ASP server side includes
>   contain matching tags, or can I open a
>   tag in one include and close it in
>   another?

The tags don't have to match; you can indeed open a tag in one include and close it in another.

Although, it might not be the best idea simply because it's confusing.